AVD users facing issue with Error code: 0x3000047 Extended error code: 0x0
Users are experiencing disconnections from Azure Virtual Desktop (AVD) machines, receiving the error code 0x3000047 with an extended error code of 0x0.
[{"Code":-2147467259,"CodeSymbolic":"ConnectionFailedAdTrustedRelationshipFailure","Time":"2024-05-30T12:01:46.7398504Z","Message":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.RDInfra.RDAgent.Service.AddUserToLocalGroupAdTrustedRelationshipFailureException' was thrown.","ServiceError":false,"Source":"RDAgent"}]
Is there a way to resolve/aviod this issue ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
